# Iterates of a stopping time

Tags: probability

I got stuck in reading PTE from Durrett.

First $T$ is a stopping time if $T$ takes value in $\{0,1,2,.....\}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\{T=n\}\in\sigma(X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n)$

In **Chapter 4.1,Page 157(Edition 4.1)**,we define the shift $θ$:$(θw)(n)=w(n+1)$  ($Ω=S^N$).

Then for any stopping time $T$ , we can define its iterates by $T_0=0$ and $T_n(w)=T_{n-1}(w)+T(\theta^{T_{n-1}}w)$.I wander **why $T_n$ is a stopping time?**

Comment: $ T_n$ is the $n$-th time that $T$ occurs. By recurrence it is enough to show that $T_2$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Sorry I am just a green hand in stochastic process. Thanks for your answer! I will read recurrence in the next section to find out the answer of my question.

Comment: No, I mean it's enough to prove that $T( \theta^T)$ is a stopping time. Then $T_2=T+T(\theta^T)$ is a stopping time since $T_1=T$.

Comment: It's not obvious that $T(θ^T)$ is a stopping time, maybe just for me. I spent hours but fail to work it out. Could you please give me the your solution?